# Alias for unpushed commits, no matter what branch I'm on?

Tags: git, git-log

I've got a git alias that looks like this:

```
[alias]
        unpushed = log origin..HEAD --pretty=format:'%h %an %s'
```

Which works great for showing "unpushed" changes when I'm on master.  But, this alias doesn't really work right when I'm on a branch.

What would the correct command be to show unpushed changes whether or not I'm on a branch?

Comment: Seems to work okay for me on a branch...what's not working for you?

Comment: It works, but it shows how the branch has diverged from master, not how my local copy has diverged from upstream, which is what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to see the outgoing commits for the current branch, you can use the following:

```
git config alias.unpushed "log @{u}.. --pretty=format:'%h %an %s'"
```

This causes `git log` to show all commits reachable from `HEAD` excluding those reachable from the upstream branch.  The `@{u}..` argument is equivalent to `@{u}..HEAD`, and `@{u}` is shorthand for the current branch's upstream commit (e.g., `origin/foo` if the checked out branch is `foo`).

If you want to see all unpushed commits from all branches, do this:

```
git config alias.unpushed "log --all --not --remotes --tags --pretty=format:'%h %an %s'"
```

The above causes `git log` to walk all references, but stop at (exclude) remote references (e.g., `origin/master`) and tags.  Git doesn't distinguish between local and remote tags, so the above assumes that all tags are remote (this isn't always true, so you may want to leave out the `--tags` argument sometimes).

I personally use the following aliases to show unpushed commits:

```
# unpushed:  graph of everything excluding pushed/tag commits
# with boundary commits (see below for 'git g' alias)
git config alias.unpushed '!git g --not --remotes --tags'

# go:  _G_raph of _O_utgoing commits with boundary commits
# (see below for 'git gb' alias)
git config alias.go '!git gb @{u}..'

# g:  _G_raph of everything with boundary commits
git config alias.g '!git gb --all'

# gb:  _G_raph of current _B_ranch (or arguments) with boundary commits
git config alias.gb '!git gbnb --boundary'

# gbnb:  _G_raph of current _B_ranch (or arguments) with _N_o _B_oundary commits
git config alias.gbnb 'log --graph --date-order --pretty=tformat:"%C(yellow)%h%Creset %C(magenta)%aE %ai%Creset %C(green bold)%d%Creset%n        %s"'
```

For simple repositories I use the `git g` alias as my primary method of exploring the commits.  For complex repositories (dozens of branches), I generally use `git gb` to show specific branches or ranges of commits.  When I want to see how `git push` will change the remote reference (my `push.default` is set to `upstream`), I use `git go`.  When I want to see if there is anything anywhere in my local repository I haven't pushed (e.g., to see if I'll lose work if I delete the clone), I use `git unpushed`.

Answer (score 1):

I use [git-wtf](https://github.com/michaelklishin/git-wtf) for this and other questions.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
git config alias.unpushed "log $(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u})..HEAD --pretty=format:'%h %an %s'"
```

It compares the full name of the upstream tracking branch (e.g. `refs/remotes/origin/master`) with HEAD. The full name is a valid refspec for your average git operation.

If you use `fetch` instead of `pull`, and want commits in *either* branch but not both, use `...` syntax instead of `..` syntax in the command.

Comment: Works but doesn't really work -- this ads an alias to the checked out tree's .gitconfig, but if I switch branches with "git checkout" the alias continues to refer to the old branch.  You can't put "$(git ...)" style shell expansions right in ~/.gitconfig which is what I want.

Comment: @slacy Ah yeah I see the error now. Upvoted Richard's answer.